# Finding the Schwarzian Derivative

Tags: derivatives

Determine the Schwarzian derivative of the following function: $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

I've plugged this into the Schawrzian derivative equation and got the following answer, but I'm not sure if it's able to be reduced anymore or if it even needs to be reduce.

$S_f(x)=\frac{(0)(2ax+b)-\frac{3}{2}(4a^2)}{(2ax+b)^2}=\frac{-6a^2+2ax+b}{(2ax+b)^2}$

Comment: I get: $ S_f (x) = \frac {-6 a^2} {(2 ax + b)^2} $

Comment: $0$ times anything is $0$